# I have a multisite install to handle different countries & currencies

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-ipn, multisite

I have a multisite install to handle different countries & currencies (xx.com/au/ & xx.com/). I have a single PayPal account.

Is there a way to have a single IPN address handle the PayPal notifications for both sub-sites? Or what's the best way to set up PayPal in this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depend on your business requirement. you can set one IPN address to handle all these transactions that come from different countries and currencies, there is no problem.
In IPN script, you can distinguish the transaction source by payment currency code. 
Feel free to let me know if any question.